# Are you allowed to use index variables in grammars?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

If we say that the grammar for the language $L = \{ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$, is:

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow A_1A_2S \mid B_1B_2S \mid Z_2\\
A_2A_1 &\rightarrow A_1A_2\\
A_2B_1 &\rightarrow B_1A_2\\
B_2A_1 &\rightarrow A_1B_2\\
B_2B_1 &\rightarrow B_1B_2\\
A_2Z_2 &\rightarrow Z_2a\\
B_2Z_2 &\rightarrow Z_2b\\
Z_2 &\rightarrow Z_1\\
A_1Z_1 &\rightarrow Z_1a\\
B_1Z_1 &\rightarrow Z_1b\\
Z_1 &\rightarrow \lambda\\
\end{align}$

Here, the characters for each word are generated in the order they appear in a word $x \in L$ in pairs $A_1A_2$ and $B_1B_2$, sorted using rules like $A_2B_1 \rightarrow B_1A_2$ and then converted with the end character, $Z_2$.

It can be seen that we could easily adapt this grammar to recognise the language $L = \{www \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$, by changing the start rule to $S \rightarrow A_1A_2A_3S \mid B_1B_2B_3S \mid Z_3$ and then adding more sorting and converting rules accordingly.

I am struggling to see how we can generalise this to the language $L = \{w^i \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*,i \ge 2\}$, however.

Can you use a rule that looks like $S \rightarrow A_1A_2\dots A_iS \mid B_1B_2\dots B_iS \mid Z_i$, where $i \ge 2$?

If so, can we use sorting rules that look like:

$A_kB_j \rightarrow B_jA_k$, where $1 \le j < k \le i$,

are you allowed to use variables in grammars like that? If so, you could just write the whole grammar as:

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow A_1A_2\dots A_iS \mid B_1B_2\dots B_iS \mid Z_i,\text{ where } i \ge 2.\\
A_kA_j &\rightarrow A_jA_k;\\
A_kB_j &\rightarrow B_jA_k;\\
B_kA_j &\rightarrow A_jB_k;\\
B_kB_j &\rightarrow B_jB_k,\text{ where } 1 \le j < k \le i.\\
A_kZ_k &\rightarrow Z_ka;\\
B_kZ_k &\rightarrow Z_kb;\\
Z_k &\rightarrow Z_{k-1},\text{ where } 1 \le k \le i.\\
Z_0 &\rightarrow \lambda\\
\end{align}$

I have never seen a grammar with variables like this though. But I guess they aren't really variables, because $i$ needs to be specified before the computation begins. So, what you would actually be doing is choosing some $i$ and then instantiating a version of that grammar, specifially for a given $i$. Once the computation has begun, there are no actual variables in the grammar and, effectively, we are just providing rules to build a grammar for the language, based on some $i$.

I can think of an algorithm for a Turing machine that could recognise that language (by partitioning the input string $w$ in all possible ways such that $|w|\text{ mod }n = 0$, where $n$ is the number of substrings, and then checking each partition to see if any of them have exactly the same substrings), so the language must be recursively enumerable - I just can't think how to write something like this as a grammar without making rules with variables (if you arent allowed to.. if you are allowed to then I think what I have is okay..)

**EDIT:**

I think I might have come up with a way of solving the problem without using index variables:

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow LZ_1XR\\
X &\rightarrow A_0X \mid B_0X \mid \lambda\\
Z_1A_0 &\rightarrow A_1A_0Z_1\\
Z_1B_0 &\rightarrow B_1B_0Z_1\\
A_0A_1 &\rightarrow A_1A_0\\
A_0B_1 &\rightarrow B_1A_0\\
B_0A_1 &\rightarrow A_1B_0\\
B_0B_1 &\rightarrow B_1B_0\\
LA_1 &\rightarrow A_1L\\
LB_1 &\rightarrow B_1L\\
Z_1R &\rightarrow RZ_0 \mid Y_0\\
A_0Z_0 &\rightarrow Z_0A_0\\
B_0Z_0 &\rightarrow Z_0B_0\\
LZ_0 &\rightarrow LZ_1\\
A_0Y_0 &\rightarrow Y_0a\\
B_0Y_0 &\rightarrow Y_0b\\
LY_0 &\rightarrow Y_1\\
A_1Y_1 &\rightarrow Y_1a\\
B_1Y_1 &\rightarrow Y_1b\\
Y_1 &\rightarrow \lambda\\
\end{align}$

Here, an initial string $w$ is generated between $L$ and $R$ markers using $A_0$ and $B_0$ non-terminals, then the $Z_1$ character is moved to the right of the string, making a copy of the word in $A_1$ and $B_1$ non-terminals which are then shuffled to the left of the $L$ marker, and this process is repeated until you have $i$ copies of the string $w$, at which point the $Z_1$ changes and runs across the string to the left changing all the non-terminals into terminals.

I think this should work fine.. but it is a pretty complicated grammar, so my initial question still remains, are you allowed to use index variables to make rules to generate grammars like I did in the original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you use a rule that looks like $S \rightarrow A_1A_2\dots A_iS \mid B_1B_2\dots B_iS \mid Z_i$, where $i \ge 2$?

No. Grammar rules consist of explicitly given finite strings of terminals and non-terminals on each side of the arrow, and a grammar may contain only finitely many rules. The first restriction rules out the "for all $i\ge 2$" part of your rule, and the second part rules out viewing that single rule as standing for the infinite sequence of rules $A_1\to B_1$, $A_1A_2\to B_1B_2$, $\dotsc$.

Note that, if rules are allowed to be infinite (in size or number) then you can write a grammar for every language, as you can just give the infinite rule $A\to s_1\mid s_2\mid \dots$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I should have thought about the fact that you could just write a grammar for any language if you allow an unbounded number of rules. Thanks for that. I like my alternative solution anyway :)